# PowerPoint template is unchangeable

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint, presentations, microsoft

I am trying to use [this template](https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/view.aspx?src=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.uibk.ac.at%2Fmedia%2Ffiler_public%2F89%2Fb8%2F89b8c1e8-27a5-4452-b7cf-07bb7dba9c41%2F02_pp_1_vorlage_16zu9_deen_2023.pptx&wdOrigin=BROWSELINK):

When using the slide-template regarding "Zitat bearbeiten" (slide 11) or the one using 2 columns with separate headers "Untertitelformat bearbeiten" (slides 7 and 8), neither text nor format of the text in quotation marks above is changable. It has no box to edit, nor does it seem to be part of some background. How do I get to change/edit it? Is the template too old for the current PowerPoint version I am using (365)?

It seems that said textboxes are no "placeholders" (as called in the masterslide options in PowerPoint). They should be placeholders though...

Answer (score 2):

They are static parts of added to the Slide Master layout.

If you go to **View** and choose the **Slide Master** under the ***Master Views*** group, you can edit those elements (and then switch back to regular view by selecting **Normal**.)

Slide 7 and 8 use the same master (*Textfolie4 + 2 Spalten*) and Slide 11 uses another one (*Textfolie7 + Zitat*).

Comment: How do I edit such a textbox to become a placeholder?

Comment: When you edit the master slide, you can delete the text box and insert a placeholder instead

Comment: Is it not possible to alter an existing text box to a placeholder?

Comment: No. You need to delete and add a placeholder text box. (How difficult is it really?...)

Comment: Thank you. Sure, but still somewhat unnecessarily complicated :)